# OpenGTS Change/edit Interface

Tags: java, jsp, ant, gps, opengts

I had been working with OpenGTS, According to what I read, the files are located in the `$GTS_HOME / build / track`, after you change/edit it as you want to edit either the CSS, JSP, etc. whatever you want, you need to compile the 
(ant track) again and ready. The problem is that I do these steps and do not work for me.

I would like to know, How can i change/edit the interface of this platform?

Comment: So, did you find an answer to your question? I am trying to find the interface of the web service too! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry brother, I still have not had any response. I hope someone will take pity on us and help us :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...files are located in the $GTS_HOME / build / track, after you
>   change/edit it as you want to edit either the CSS, JSP, etc...

that is the correct procedure.
only that after

```
ant track
```

is necessary

```
ant track.deploy
```

too.
And in some cases , restart Tomcat to see the changes .